# create image for database diagram in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-diagram

I have created database diagram in sql server. But I have to take 15 more tables in db diagram. Then i take screenshot. But i can't take screenshot more than 5 table. So I take screenshot 2 or more times. If sql server is automatically create image and if it is in single screenshot means it is ok. Any way to do this?

[image]

This is my screenshot. I ask Any chance to take 15 tables in single screenshot through sql server?

Comment: what do you mean taking screenshot? really capture the displaying screen to image?

Comment: You mean Generating an E-R diagram?

Comment: No. not E-R diagram. I talk about Database diagrams(schema structure).

Comment: Hai Shivan, I update my question with screenshot. If u see u know what i am asking.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Just open the diagram in SSMS, right click on the diagram surface (on the blank space between the tables, not the tables themselves) and then click the "Copy Diagram To Clipboard" option.

You can then paste the full diagram into whatever program you want.

Comment: I have like 50 odd tables.. While copy pasting it to Paint, I don't see table contents(columns) in the copied content. I see onlt table headings with black box. Should i do anything else?

Comment: Nice feature, but when I paste it in a graphics tool I get an image with a horribly low resolution... not able to read anything

Comment: Did anyone ever answer the low resolution question? How do you raise the resolution of the image that's exported?

Comment: When you select "Copy Diagram To Clipboard", SSMS use the current zoom. If you want a "higher resolution", then select zoom 100% or more and reclick right button, select "Copy Diagram To Clipboard" and it will work. Very confusing "export to image" method ...